# Is there a function in PHP where I can separate them

Tags: php

[image: Problem]

Is there a way to seperate them to array
like

```
0:Apple,Orange,Watermelon
1:One,Two,Three
3:Dog,Cat,Mouse
```

```
$lines = array();
foreach(preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $decode) as $line){
                array_push($lines,$line);   
                }
```

[image: output is this]

Comment: is it every 3 items or is that random?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius it's random

Comment: But the pattern of a blank line ( `\r\n` ) to separate the output is always thus?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius i plan to seperate them by ( \r\n )

Comment: What I mean is in the above image the boundary appears to be 2 linefeeds

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius   hmm yea my solution not working to what i expect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str="apple\r\norange\r\nmango\r\npomegranate\r\n\r\ncat\r\ndog\r\nhorse\r\nhippopotamus\r\ngiraffe\r\nrabidbehampstergbabble\r\n\r\nmale\r\nfemale\r\nplate\r\n";
# is essentially the same as
/* 
    apple
    orange
    mango
    pomegranate
    
    cat
    dog
    horse
    hippopotamus
    giraffe
    rabidbehampstergbabble
    
    male
    female
    plate
*/
    
// initially break apart on designated boundary \r\n\s
$a=array_filter( preg_split('@(\r\n\s)@', trim($str) ) );
// process each portion of the initial array
$a=array_map( function( $n ){
    // trim the item and return an imploded string after splitting on newline
    return implode( ',', array_filter( preg_split( '@(\r\n)@', trim( $n ) ) ) );
},$a );

printf('<pre>%s</pre>',print_r($a,1));
```

Which yields:

```
Array
(
    [0] => apple,orange,mango,pomegranate
    [1] => cat,dog,horse,hippopotamus,giraffe,rabidbehampstergbabble
    [2] => male,female,plate
)
```

Comment: damn, nice it's working now Thanks a lot! and have a nice day